# Customizing nautilus status bar

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I would like to know how one would be able to make it so when you have a video selected in nautilus, the status bar shows the length of the video. I know you can right-click the file and view the properties to see the video length, So I was hoping there is a way to extract this information somehow and display it on the status bar.

Comment: __Whoever close voted this as too broad,__ can you tell us where you found _too many answers_ for this question?

Comment: Knowing the GNOME developers this is impossible without a modification of the source code. You could try alternative file managers though.

Comment: @Anwar It is too broad since nautilus is still a living  software. The answer could range from Not possible to Compile it yourself depends on which version are you talking about.

Comment: @Syakur Not possible is an answer and compile it yourself too! Don't know what's the problem with living software though